# Is there a way to shorten my SQL Server code

Tags: sql-server

I'm quite new to SQL server and basically I have this query that uses two table and I was wondering if there's an easy way to shorten the code, the repeating of the table names looks pretty bad.

```
SELECT        
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.OrderID, dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.Created, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.CreatedBy, dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.Updated, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.UpdatedBy, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.CUT, dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.CDL, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.Domain, dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.ProductID, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.Amount, dbo.atbl_Sales_Products.ProductName, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_Products.Supplier, dbo.atbl_Sales_Products.Quantity AS TotalQuantity, 
    dbo.atbl_Sales_Products.Price, dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.PrimKey
FROM
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.atbl_Sales_Products ON dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines.ProductID = dbo.atbl_Sales_Products.ProductID
```

There has to be an easier way to do this. Thank you.

Comment: Use `table alias` and refer that.

Comment: To table-alias or not table-alias is opinion based.

Comment: [Three-part and four-part column references are deprecated anyway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/deprecated-database-engine-features-in-sql-server-2016?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15) and so you shouldn't be using them for that reason

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **tables alias** to shorten that code:

```
SELECT        
    ol.OrderID, 
    ol.Created, ol.CreatedBy, ol.Updated, ol.UpdatedBy, 
    ol.CUT, ol.CDL, 
    ol.Domain, ol.ProductID, ol.Amount,  
    p.ProductName, p.Supplier, p.Quantity AS TotalQuantity, p.Price, 
    ol.PrimKey
FROM
    dbo.atbl_Sales_OrdersLines ol
INNER JOIN
    dbo.atbl_Sales_Products p ON ol.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

The `ol` and `p` are table alias that you can choose - I recommend choosing something that is "intuitive", e.g. "ol" for "Order Lines", "p" for "Product" - that makes reading (and understanding) your SQL code much easier

Comment: Thank you. can't mark it as an answer for 5 more minutes, but will do so after.